# How to call the result of fetch() request in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have  `fetch()` request out of `Component` :

```
           fetch('/json.bc', {
            method: 'get',
        })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(text => {
            let MaindataTotal = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
            $(document).trigger('update_result', [MaindataTotal])
            }).catch(error => console.error(error))
```

And in my `Component` I want to use the response of `fetch()` request:

```
      class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            library: null,
            InvoiceTotal:{},

        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
            $(document).on('update_result',(event,MaindataTotal)=>{
            console.log(MaindataTotal)
            this.setState(state => ({
                    ...state,
                    InvoiceTotal: MaindataTotal
                }), () => {

                })
            })
    }
.
.
.

}
```

but there is no result in  `$(document).on()`. 
`console.log(MaindataTotal)` returns nothing.
I know that I can call `fetch()` request directly in `componentDidMount() {}` but I want to call it in this way.Why nothing happens in  `$(document).on('update_result',(event,MaindataTotal)=>{....}` even `consol.log('ok')`?
**Edit**

```
      fetch('/json.bc', {
            method: 'get',
        })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(text => {
            let MaindataTotal = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
            const fetchJSON = () => {
            return MaindataTotal;
            }
            }).catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing jQuery events and React in one application, which is not a good idea. Easier way would be just to return a propcessed response from fetch and set it to the state:

```
const fetchJSON = () => {
  return fetch('/json.bc', {
      method: 'get',
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"')))
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

```
componentDidMount() {
 fetchJSON().then((resp) => {
  console.log(resp);
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      InvoiceTotal: resp
    }), () => {

    })
  })
 })
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Clarity. Is it possible to look at **Edit**  part  of my code?Why is not possible to call `fetchJSON = () => {}` in response of `fetch()` request?

Comment: When I call `fetchJSON = () => {}` in response of `fetch()` request there is this error: `fetchJSON is not defined`

Comment: I there an way to call it in response of `fetch()` request?

Comment: @sahar I recommend you look at the fetch usage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch. You shouldn't define `fetchJSON` inside of the fetch response callback, you need to wrap your whole fetch block in a function, so you can call it from your react components. What you're trying to do doesn't make any sense to be honest.

Comment: Actually when I call `fetch()` inside of Component or in the way you suggested me, by loading the page , after 3 or 4 second the `json.bc` page will be shown in `XHR` of `network` tab in my browser. but when It is called out of component by loading the page `json.bc` page will be shown in XHR of network tab quickly without wasting 3 or 4 seconds. Because of that I thought to call the `json.bc` page out of component to be loaded as soon as possible.Sorry for bad explanation:| Does it make any sense?

Comment: You still need to load that data at some point, you can show a loading indicator in your component meanwhile, to have a better UX.